# why is it not recognizing my argument as an object? Is my typeof method incorrect?

Tags: javascript

We are going to complete a function that takes in one parameter, possibly an object, and returns whether the input in an object or not. Your function should create several variables (isObject, isNotAnArray, and isObjectAndNotAnArray). Assign isObject to an application of the typeof operator to the input. Assign isNotAnArray to a call to the Array.isArray() method with the ! operator applied as well. Assign isObjectAndNotAnArray to the two previous variabes combined with the && operator, and return the isObjectAndNotAnArray variable. Below are examples of the code running, assuming that you will have completed the described function: isAnObject.

```js
var resultBoolean1 = isAnObject([1, 2, 3]);
console.log('should log false:', resultBoolean1);

var resultBoolean2 = isAnObject({name: 'Tom', friend: 'Jerry'});
console.log('should log true:', resultBoolean2);
```

My code:

```js
function isAnObject(input) {
  var isObject = typeof input === 'object';
  var isNotAnArray = Array.isArray(!input);
  var isObjectAndNotAnArray = isObject && isNotAnArray;
  return isObjectAndNotAnArray;// create an isObject variable
  // assign it to whether the input is an object type
  // create an isNotAnArray variable
  // assign it to whether the input is not an array
  // create an isObjectAndNotAnArray variable
  // assign it to a combination of isObject AND isNotAnArray
  // return the isObjectAndNotAnArray variable
}
```

It tells me: it returns true when input parameter is an object

> Error:
> expected false to deeply equal true

Comment: What do you expect `!input` to be? Additionally, whomever is teaching you this is misleading you. Arrays in JavaScript are indeed Objects - they are just special ones that are a bit different internally. But no surprise is the inaccuracy in this regard. Just thought you should know.

Comment: What does the text you have added at the end mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exclamation mark is in the wrong place

```
  var isNotAnArray = Array.isArray(!input);
```

To

```
  var isNotAnArray = !Array.isArray(input);
```

Because you want to negate the boolean and not the object itself

Just for cleaner code I would clean it up and shorten it:

```
function isObject(input) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Object]';
}
```

This is a different approach but basically it takes your value and makes it into a string, so arrays are ruled out and then it checks if the string is [object Object]. The reason I prefer this is because values like "null" or "undefined" behave weirdly and are considered objects by how you have it defined, so this method opens up your usage to all variable types.

Comment: Thank you! This community is so harsh to new coders. Appreciate it.

Comment: If it is the correct answer please mark it as so, so that it can be closed off. I added a cleaner method that works with all JS variable types